# <<Flutter>> Duvida no retorno do Map - //Map <String, dynamic>// - esta voltando: null

Tags: json, flutter, map

vou deixar o bloco do codigo --(Recupera api da https://viacep.com.br/, os dados listados no cod, fim de estudos e treinamento)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';



class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

    String _resultado = "Resultado";


  _recuperarCep() async {

    //String cep = "01001000";
    String url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/";
    http.Response response;

    response = await http.get(url);

    //Map<String, dynamic> retorno = json.decode( response.body );

    Map <String, dynamic> retorno = jsonDecode(response.body);

    String logradouro = retorno["Logradouro"];
    String complemento = retorno["Complemento"];
    String bairro = retorno["Bairro"];
    String localidade = retorno["Localidade"];


    setState(() {
      _resultado = "${logradouro},${complemento},${bairro},${localidade},";
    });

    print(
        "Resposta logradouro: ${logradouro} complemento ${complemento} bairro ${bairro} localidade ${localidade}"
   );

    //print("Resposta:"+ response.statusCode.toString());
    //print("Resposta:"+ response.body);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Consumo de serviço web"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_resultado),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Clique aqui"),
              onPressed: _recuperarCep,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preste mais atenção na API que você está utilizando... Ela retorna esse JSON abaixo e você esta lendo o mesmo de forma errada.

> ```
> {
>   "cep": "01001-000",
>   "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
>   "complemento": "lado ímpar",
>   "bairro": "Sé",
>   "localidade": "São Paulo",
>   "uf": "SP",
>   "unidade": "",
>   "ibge": "3550308",
>   "gia": "1004"
> }
> ```

O problema não é o `Map<>` retornado, mas sim como você está lendo os dados dele...

*Flutter é caseSensitive, então...*

Mude isso aqui

```
String logradouro = retorno["Logradouro"];
String complemento = retorno["Complemento"];
String bairro = retorno["Bairro"];
String localidade = retorno["Localidade"];
```

Para

```
String logradouro = retorno["logradouro"];
String complemento = retorno["complemento"];
String bairro = retorno["bairro"];
String localidade = retorno["localidade"];
```

Comment: perfeito deu certo, foi uma desatenção minha, sou muito grato a sua ajuda vlw obrigado.